# How to add input values in an array without using push() unshift() methods?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [],
    var inputText = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
var showArray = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML;
stackAdd = function() {
    if (inputText != "") {
        var i = myArray.length;
        myArray[i] = inputText;
        showArray = myArray[i];
        inputText = "";
    }
}
```

I want to add my input values to the array. No limit to the values. please correct the code......

Comment: Show your html code.

Comment: How many elements do you want to add?

Comment: Well first of all your loop won't run.. You're saying arrayElements = []; therefor the length of arrayElements is 0. Then in your loop you say that i = 0 and i should be less than the arrayElements.length which is 0. I don't get what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>stack </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
 <section>
  <form>
  <p><input type="text" id="textbox"/></p>
  <p><label id="display">Stack:</label></p>
  <p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="stackAdd()"/></p>
  <p><input type="button" value="RemoveFirst" onclick="removeFirst()"/></p>
  <p><input type="button" value="RemoveLast" onclick="removeLast()"/></p>
  </form> 
 </section>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="stackusingloops.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I want to add the input box value to the array.....pls correct the code..if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you should change a condition in this line (counting the length of correct array):

`for (i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {`

Initially the `arrayElements.length` will be 0, so your loop is not going to run.

Also, **you should change the way you selecting your elements** in the DOM.
To be able to get array of elements you should use `document.getElementsByClassName()` function

In this way you should give your elements not id, but class, for example:

`<input class="textbox" type="text" value="" />`

Then you should rely on amount of your elements to make your loop works.

So, count them before the loop:

`var totalElements = document.getElementsByClassName('textbox').length`

and then in the loop condition use that length:

`for (i = 0; i < totalElements.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

I created this example for you, it's quite simple, there is no need for a loop, when you only have 1 element you wish to add to the array from.

https://jsfiddle.net/6xpovrvh/

It has then following HTML and Javascript:

**HTML**

```
<button id="test" onclick="Add();">
    Test
</button>

<div id="TestDiv">
    Bla
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var arrayElements = [];
function Add() {
    var count = arrayElements.length;
    arrayElements[count] = "Test" + count;
    document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML += arrayElements[count];
};
```

Comment: @Creator - Did you try the fiddle? I can see you changed the code in you question, you still need to provide the html.

Comment: your fiddle is working fine...but mine alone still not get the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [];

function stackAdd() {
    if (document.getElementById("textbox").value) {
        var i = myArray.length;
        document.getElementById("textbox").value += myArray[i];
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += myArray[i] + ',' + ' ';
        document.getElementById("textbox").value = "";
    }
}
```

I get the answer to my question. Its working....